# Cannot control css bottom property via javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Ok so I have one div and inside it a canvas.
from my html file:

```
<div id="container">
    <canvas id="game" width="600px" height="2000px"></canvas>
</div>
```

from css file:

```
#game{
    /*background-color: #99CC00;*/
    background:-moz-linear-gradient(top, #00b7ea 0%, #008793 14%, #004b9b 43%, #1f00ea 74%, #008793 89%, #009ec3 100%);
    bottom: 0px;
    position: absolute;
}
#container{
    position: relative;
    width: 600px;
    height: 500px;
}
```

What i want to do is to control the 'bottom' value of #game that is:

```
($("#game").css("bottom")),
```

To put it in an if statement and if true, to change it automatically.

But when I try there is a problem that I cannot understand.
I have a variable called `s`. Where s will be the amount that should be changed, it's not a fixed number.

when I tried `($("#game").css("bottom", -s));`
nothing happened, so to check it I did the following:

`alert( ($("#game").css("bottom", -s)) );` the reply was [object Object].

while if I just do `alert( ($("#game").css("bottom")) );` the reply is correctly 0px.

What am I missing? Help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried `parseInt()` on `s` to ensure that it's numeric?

Comment: try adding `px` - `$("#game").css("bottom", -s + 'px')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.css(name, value)` will set the css property of the `name` equal to the `value`. It will not alter the value like doing `x += 1` would change a variable.

Therefore you should be doing something like:

```
var oldValue = parseInt($("#game").css("bottom"));
$("#game").css("bottom", (oldValue - s) + "px")
```

The `parseInt` is necessary, because as you said it returns `0px`, which is a string.

Comment: It still needs a unit, unless the value is actually 0.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the value and set as:

```
$( "div" ).on( "click", function() {
    $( this ).css({
    height: function( index, value ) {
        return value * 1.2;
    }
    });
});
```

The `1.2` is same as `r` in your code, when you click on div , the 'div' height is increased automatically . It may help you out.